# Why my code is categorized as external in CppDepend?

Tags: cppdepend

I have a large code-base that I'm trying to analyze with CppDepend to see if it will provide useful information to us, but it categorizes much of the code wrongly as external which makes the analysis skewed. I cannot figure out the basis of this categorization. I am feeding it a compile_commands.json compilation database, but I have also tried with project maker with more or less the same results.

Is there a way to force non-external categorization of a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a used include file has no implementation in your the source files of your project, it's considered as external.